# different of defining object inside and outside loops in Java

Tags: java, loops

I was struggling with part of my code today to read some data from a file and add them to an object as its properties (I'm aware of how to add/read object in file without this hassle but wanted to do it this way) as below:

file is like this:

```
111,john,23.1
222,jack,22.5
234,adam,12.8
```

I was trying to read this file using following:

```
public ArrayList<Staff> LoadAllStaffs(){
    ArrayList<Staff> staffs = new ArrayList<Staff>();
    File file = new File(stafffile);
    Staff tmpstaff = new Staff();
    try {
        BufferedReader inputfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stafffile));
        String tmp;
        while((tmp = inputfile.readLine()) != null){
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tmp , ",");
            tmpstaff.setID(Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken()));
            tmpstaff.setFirstName(st.nextToken());
            tmpstaff.setSalary(Double.valueOf(st.nextToken()));
            staffs.add(tmpstaff);
            }
        } 
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return staffs;
}
```

using `println` this output shown from the returned `ArrayList`:

```
234,adam,12.8
234,adam,12.8
234,adam,12.8
```

I just moved the `Staff tmpstaff = new Staff();` inside the while loop and it shows what it should.

why this is happening? I read -even here- that defining variables (well, here its an Object ) inside or outside loops doesn't make any difference.

Comment: What matters here is not where the variable is declared. What matters is: how many Staff instances do you create. If you create just one instance and add it N times to the list, then of course the list will contain N times the same object, containing the same values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not creating a new `Staff` instance inside the loop, you are reusing the same instance for all the iterations. So,  you overwrite the values and add the same object.

Move

```
Staff tmpstaff = new Staff();
```

to the first line inside the loop.

UPDATE: To address `Vash`'s comment, the issue here is that can be explained as that, if you want to store 3 objects, you need to create such 3 objects. You can reuse the **reference** (the `tmpstaff` variable) and effectively where it is defined it is not important (as long as all references to it are in the same scope. But you must create the 3 objects, which means 3 `new` commands.

UPDATE 2: To put things simpler, the text `I read -even here- that defining variables (well, here its an Object ) inside or outside loops doesn't make any difference.` means that

```
File file = new File(stafffile);
Staff tmpstaff = null; // or simpler, Staff tmpstaff;
try {
   ...
   while((tmp = inputfile.readLine()) != null){
     tmpstaff = new Staff();
     ...
```

and

```
   while((tmp = inputfile.readLine()) != null){
     Staff tmpstaff = new Staff();
     ...
```

are equivalent.

Comment: Just got lucky when reloading the question list :-D

Comment: I mentioned that I did that, was wondering why its acting like this. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The operator `new` is responsible for "object creation" called instance. So when you create him outside the loop you have only one instance, that you modify every loop run. When you create that object inside the loop you have separate instance for each run.

Answer (score 2):

Well Java operates by reference on Objects. Because you are creating only one Staff() Object, there's only one Reference. Therefore, in the while Loop you change just the attributes of the Object and add the same Reference three times to the List.

You can define the variables outside the loop, but you have to instantiate a new Object inside the loop so it lookes like this:

```
Staff tmpStaff
while((tmp = inputfile.readLine()) != null){
tmpStaff = new Staff();
[additional Code here]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a new Staff on each pass of the loop, then you have to do the creation inside of the loop before using it.

Done outside the loop as you did, you created a new Staff indeed, but that same keeps being used each time.

A new object is created only when the new keyword is used.